# Binding Data Table to DataGrid using View Model

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have a requirement where I need to display data from a `DataTable` as it is, i.e. no editing required for the cells. The other requirement is that I need to display `Combobox` as header of Each Column.
Secondly, The First Column needs to be a `checkbox`, checking which grays out the row. I thought it should be feasible with `DataGrid`, but I am not sure, as I am not able to find a way to do it.

Can please somebody help me out. Please note that I wish to do it the MVVM way and not write code in xaml.cs

Eagerly looking forward for a response.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT : code added though its not much...**
.xaml

```
<DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,274,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="321" Width="981" AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=UploadedProductData, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn CanUserReorder="False" CanUserResize="False">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

In the view model of main window -

```
DataTable _uploadedProductData;
        public DataTable UploadedProductData
        {
            get { return _uploadedProductData; }
            set 
            {
                _uploadedProductData = value; 
            }
        }
```

The above is the property.

In the xaml.cs -  I set the above property - on some button event

```
 ViewModel.UploadedProductData = dt;
```

Comment: There are many tutorials out there which will help you, but I'm not going to search for them and just give you the answer. The one advice I'd give you is don't go with the datatable as is, but rather turn it into a collection (after all that's the MVVM way); either manually or with the help of some library, map the rows to instances of a class. Then you can add a separate property that represents the checkbox, and solve everything else with bindings. The DataGrid has many options for various templates which you'll need to specify, and that's about it.

Comment: It is becoming increasingly common for new users to come to `StackOverflow` and ask for help with complete projects. That is *not* what StackOverflow is for. The idea is that each developer *does their own work* and only comes here to ask how to fix a particular issue, whilst providing examples of their code. From the [StackOverflow help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), *Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.* Please read the help pages.

Comment: Yep- Actually I did go through some tutorials, but I was uncertain as to how to construct the template for the GRID, and that's where my major problem is,... the approach. Further, I have provided the DataTable to make things simpler, I can surely do it with a class in the final version. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Then you should show what code you have and explain what difficulties you are having with it.

Comment: @Sheridan - did not mean to upset the objective of stackoverflow, my idea was to request an approach if it was even possible in DataGrid, as I have constructed jquery templates of such sort in asp.net.  I was thinking of somebody saying that 'buddy your approach is wrong - try to do it this way'... But any ways, if the editors of stack overflow think that I my question is not reasonably scoped, I will request them to remove it. Also I have noticed, people who are asking help on projects, at times, seek the approach...its the perception that leads to define the 'reasonable scope'.

Comment: Everything that you stated in your requirements is entirely possible in WPF. Most things are possible with WPF. Now that you have provided some code, I can see that you are missing the required [`INotifyPropertyChanged` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx)... click the link for help with this. You will need to implement this to have the UI update after property values have changed... do you see how including a code example is already working for you?

Comment: @Sheridan - I have implemented - INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyDataErrorInfo in my view model. What I am missing here primarily - (I think) 1) is the structure of the Data template to accomodate chekcbox, if this can be done via template, in the first place. 2) Binding my Datatable cell with TextBlock

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything that you stated in your requirements is entirely possible in WPF. Most things are possible with WPF. Now that you have provided some code, I can see that you are missing the required [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) interface... click the link for help with this. You will need to implement this to have the UI update after property values have changed... do you see how including a code example is already working for you?

It *is* indeed possible to create a `DataTemplate` to define what is seen in the `Header` section of a `DataGrid`. You can think of a `DataTemplate` as a tiny view for a particular piece of data and you can set a `DataTemplate` to the `Header` using the `DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate` property as you have almost got:

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <!--Define how you want the header to look here-->
        <DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
</DataGrid>
```

Now, when it comes to binding to the cells, it really depends on the object that you are using. In WPF, it is customary (but not compulsory) to create data type objects that represent your data accurately. In your case, I'm going to assume that you will just use your `DataTable` object and so it is the column names that are important.

It is best to use the `DataGridTextColumn` column for displaying text and you *could* also choose to use the `DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate` instead if you want the `Header` to be different for different columns:

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=ColumnName0}">
        <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
            <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
        </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
    </DataGridTextColumn>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" Binding="{Binding Path=ColumnName1}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name" Binding="{Binding Path=ColumnName2}" />
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Now I'm guessing that you're going to ask how to populate the `ComboBox.ItemsSource` item collection next, but I'm running out of time. For that, I'll refer you to the [WPF ComboBox in DataGridTemplateColumn with alternate ItemsSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5399859/wpf-combobox-in-datagridtemplatecolumn-with-alternate-itemssource) post and say that if that doesn't help you, you could easily find this information from an internet search.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for the response. Now, this works, and I was able to bind my datatable. And for combobox, I will manage as I have done that on my other form. Thanks once again !!! After looking at the code you provided - I feel foolish !!    In my search I never got hold of - **DataGridTextColumn** I was, all this time, trying to bind TextBlock with the Datatable cell - somehow.

Comment: Hey, it wasn't so long ago that I was making similar mistakes... it's all part of the learning experience.